# jQuery click event, after appending content

Tags: jquery

Wondering why the example below doesn't work?

```
<a id="load_list" href="#">Load the list</a>

<ul></ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#load_list').click(function() {
        $('ul').append('<li><a href="#">Click here</a></li>');
        return false;
    });
    $('ul li a').click(function() {
        alert('Thank you for clicking');
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: -1.  My question was incorrectly downvoted because some of the information provided was incorrect, appearing as though my answer was completely incorrect.

Comment: Doesn't take a genius to figure out I've only posted part of the code that wasn't working. Thanks for your input tho.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Because the elements that you are appending do not exist when you define the the `click` handler, they are created dynamically. To fix this you can use the [delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) method from jQuery.

```
$('ul').delegate('a','click',function() {
    // your code here ...
});
```

**Online example:** http://jsfiddle.net/J5QJ9/

Comment: As Bless Yahu says, it is better to use delegate, see nettuts explanation on that: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-the-difference-between-live-and-delegate/

Comment: A bit of further information (My apologies for dodgy formatting): Old: `$("#Item1").click(function(e) {` New: `$(document).delegate("#Item1", "click", function(e) {` Even Newer: `$(document).on("click", "#Item", function(e) {`

Comment: `.live` has been removed as of jQuery version 1.9, so `.delegate` or `.on` is the way to go.

Comment: `.on` didn't work for me although i have jQuery 1.11

Answer (score 9):

From jQuery 1.7 you can use the .on() handler to bind the newly created element ot the 'click' event:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#load_list').click(function() {
        $('ul').append('<li><a href="#">Click here</a></li>').on('click', 'ul li a', function () {
            alert('thank you for clicking');
        });
    });
</script>
```

(this is with the original example).

Answer (score 9):

```
$(document).on('click','ul li a', function(){
      // Content Code
});
```

Answer (score 3):

.live is deprecated as of 1.7.
Try this (jquery 2.1.4):

Html:

```
<a id="load_list" href="#">Load the list</a>

<ul></ul>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $('#load_list').click(function() {
   $('ul').html("");    

   $("<li/>", {
        "class" : "someClass",
        text: "Click here",
        click: function() {
          alert($(this).text());
        }
      }).appendTo('ul');
  });
});
```

or something like this (but I didn't find how to attach click to the anchor):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#load_list').click(function() {
   $('ul').html("");

   $('<li><a href="#">Click here</a></li>').on({
      click: function() {
        alert("hoi");
      }
    }).appendTo("ul");
 });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this new code, it removes existing click events for the old elements and then adds them again for both the old and new.

```
<a id="load_list" href="#">Load the list</a>

<ul></ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#load_list').click(function() {
        $('ul').append('<li><a href="#">Click here</a></li>');
        $('ul li a').unbind('click', thanks());//Remove existing binds
        $('ul li a').bind('click', thanks());//Remove existing binds
        return false;
    });
    function thanks() {
        alert('Thank you for clicking');
        return false;
    });
    $('ul li a').bind('click', thanks());
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the downvote whoever you are. :/ I gave proper new code with comments.

Comment: Probably because this has to be the most painful way possible.

Answer (score 0):

because you are apply the click event before the element is place in the dom you need to use [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)