# Using 'this' for dynamically added html code

Tags: jquery

So im refering to this question
[jQuery click event, after appending content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5589491/jquery-click-event-after-appending-content)

As I see, I can still call a function by clicking on dynamically added html code.

But for example I have the following code:

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    $(".container").after("<div class='article'><input type='button' id='button' /></div>");
}   

$('body').on('click', '#button', function () {
    $(this).parent().addClass("newClass");  // Of course this doesnt work because of 'this'
});
```

How can I still use 'this' for dynamically added html code?

Comment: id of the five buttons are conflicting i think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have a loop and you are appending an element with same id which should have to be unique each element.

```
.after("<div class='article'><input type='button' class='button' /></div>");
```

change it to class and use it:

```
$('body').on('click', '.button', function () {
    $(this).parent().addClass("newClass"); 
});
```

---

The question you have not asked but i need to mention it to clarify:

**What happens when there are same ids in the DOM?**

When browser goes for lookup the DOM node with that id and if it found in the DOM it stops the lookup for other. So result is any event bound on that id will only be registered for one id.

below is the test case:

```js
$('#button').click(function(){
    alert(this.textContent);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='button'>Click1</button>
<button id='button'>Click2</button>
<button id='button'>Click3</button>
<button id='button'>Click4</button>
```