# Where to add 'delegate' or 'on' method to this jquery code?

Tags: jquery, delegates, append

I'd whittled down [this jquery example](http://www.encodedna.com/2013/07/dynamically-add-remove-form-elements-using-jquery-demo.htm) so that it creates and removes a div > ul element upon clicking the "Add" or "Remove" buttons. In my project, I need the newly created elements to be added to the DOM and to be "recognized" by some other javascript code, and from what I understand, this is what the delegate method does.

jsfiddle.net/ot2xja19/1  (original fiddle needed jquery, corrected by @Rory)

```
$('#btAdd').click(function() {
    var tileCount = $('.layer.tile').length;
    if (tileCount <= 19) {
        $('#multi').append('<div class="layer tile"><div class="tile__name">List ' + (tileCount + 1) + '</div><ul class="tile__list"></ul></div>');
    }
});

// REMOVE ELEMENTS ONE PER CLICK.
$('#btRemove').click(function() {
    var tileCount = $('.layer.tile').length;
    if (tileCount > 1)
        $('.layer.tile:last').remove()
    else if (tileCount == 1) {
        $('#btSubmit').remove();
        $('#btAdd').prop('disabled', false).addClass('bt');
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking exactly, however your fiddle doesn't work as you haven't included jQuery. Here's a fixed version https://jsfiddle.net/ot2xja19/1/

Comment: Also, here's an updated version which follows much better practices https://jsfiddle.net/ot2xja19/2/

Comment: Thanks. I'm combining the above code with Sortable Drag and Drop (http://rubaxa.github.io/Sortable/). I want to generate a new ul list by clicking a button, that you can then drop li's into, which is what sortable does. The problem is with my code above, the newly created lists don't function with the sortable js code, because it doesn't know they've been added.    Edit, ok your cleaner jquery is helpful, I may be able to figure it out from there. Also this was helpful... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5589491/jquery-click-event-after-appending-content

Comment: Note that the answer in that question is now very outdated. The `delegate()` method is deprecated, you should use `on()` instead. The original version is `$('ul').delegate('a', 'click', fn)`, which should now be `$('ul').on('click', 'a', fn)` in jQuery 1.7+