# dynamic targeting of the last child of a div (matching game)

Tags: jquery

i'm making a matching game , the idea is to append 5 images to both sides and then append a 6th image to the left side , and the user has to click on that last added image and then it will be deleted and another 6 images will be appended to the left side (5 to the right) and then the user will have to click on the 11th image in the left div , on the first click every thing runs as intended but after that , when i click on the last added image nothing happen !!.

I've tried every way of accessing the last child of a div and they all returned the same problem.

this is the whole code ::

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Pick The Difference !</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        margin:auto;
        width:1000px;

        background-color: blue;
    }
    #left {
      width : 495px;
      height : 600px;
      background-color : yellow;
    }
    #mid {
      width : 10px;
      height : 600px;
      background-color : black;
    }
    #right {
      width : 495px;
      height : 600px;
      background-color : orange;
    }
    div {

    }
    img:hover{
        background-color: blue;
    }
    img {
      position: absolute;
      border:10px;
      border-radius: 300px;
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
    }
    .leftimg{
        margin-left: 181px;
    }
    .rightimg{
        margin-left: 691px;
    }
</style>
<body>
<div id="left"></div>
<div id="mid"></div>
<div id="right"></div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        function generate(){

            for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {
                var randTop = Math.floor(Math.random()*500);
                var randLeft = Math.floor(Math.random()*401);
                $("#left").append('<img class="leftimg" src="http://bahaazidan.pe.hu/Smiley.png" style="top:' +randTop+'px;'+'left:'+randLeft+'px";'+ '/>');
                $("#left").append('<img class="rightimg" src="http://bahaazidan.pe.hu/Smiley.png" style="top:' +randTop+'px;'+'left:'+randLeft+'px";'+ '/>');
            }
            $("#left").append('<img class="leftimg" src="http://bahaazidan.pe.hu/Smiley.png" style="top:' +Math.floor(Math.random()*500)+'px;'+'left:'+Math.floor(Math.random()*401)+'px";'+ '/>');
        }
        generate();
        $("#left img:last-child").click(function(){
            $("#left img:last-child").remove();
            generate();
        });

    });
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5589491/jquery-click-event-after-appending-content)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code:

```
$("#left img:last-child").click(function() {
  $("#left img:last-child").remove();
  generate();
});
```

The `.click()` event handler running on `$(document).ready()` like this will bind specifically to the element that it matches at runtime - but it won't dynamically match future elements with that selector.

Using the `.on()` handler on an unchanging parent element will fix this:

```
$("#left").on('click', 'img:last-child', function() {
  $(this).remove();
  generate();
});
```

Comment: thanks alot m8 , it worked .
can you explain "this" to me please

Comment: @BahaaZidan Glad it helped, and sure. When you're inside a jQuery function that was tied to an element, `$(this)` is a jQuery selector that refers to the current element. In this case, it's the `img:last-child`. Read more here: https://remysharp.com/2007/04/12/jquerys-this-demystified