# How to delete a parent tr

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

**UPDATE 1:**

I'm wondering if it has anything to do with the button being within the element which is being deleted, so it would end up deleting the button which does the deleting too?  That might not be the problem, I was just typing that I'm thinking.

I've just tried:

```
$( "input.btnX" ).click(function(event) {
    alert("test");
});
```

and I don't get an alert...  Should I be using `live` or is it `on` now because the buttons along with the table are dynamically generated.

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

I have a table (dynamically generated, so I won't know how many tr's it has in tbody which looks something like this:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>col1</td>
            <td>col2</td>
            <td><input type="button" class="btnX" name="x" value="x" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>col1</td>
            <td>col2</td>
            <td><input type="button" class="btnX" name="x" value="x" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How do I delete the parent tr if an x button is clicked?  So in this example, if the bottom x is clicked, it should remove the bottom tr.

I've tried this:

```
$( "input.btnX" ).click(function(event) {
    $(this).parent('tr').remove();
});
```

But nothing happens.

Comment: check this stackoverflow link [Link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5589420/select-tr-by-id-with-jquery

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Just use

```
    $( "input.btnX" ).click(function(event) {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
```

Or

```
  $( "input.btnX" ).click(function(event) {
        $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    });
```

As what you are doing is going to the parent which is the tr and then looking for a tr

See an example here http://jsfiddle.net/gYDUF/

If your table is beeing rendered by javascript you may also have to change your click on

```
$("input.btnX" ).live(click, function(){

     $(this).closest("tr").remove();
});
```

Comment: Work fine for me see the added jsfiddle are you running your code in document ready

Comment: You're got a hard coded table in your jsfiddle example, will this work with tables created on the fly dynamically?

Comment: See last part off the new update try changing your click to .live() or use $(document).delegate(selector, events, data, handler);

Comment: Worked like a charm, +1

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$( "input.btnX" ).click(function(event) {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

As the tr is not a direct parent to the input element.

EDIT:
If the Table is built dynamically, try using

```
$( "input.btnX" ).live("click", function(event) {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$( "input.btnX" ).on("click", function(event) {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

This should do the job and avoids deprecated ".live()" (as already mentioned).

Also see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h9DKW/8/)

Comment: See [jQuery .on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and    
[jQuery .live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) (.live() is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7)

Comment: I am using jquery 1.7.2 via `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js` and `on` doesn't work for me, but `live` does.  Any idea why?

Comment: Take a look at the link you posted. This isn't the syntax for using `.on()` for delegated events; you need to do `$(document).on('click','input.btnX', function() { ... })` where `document` can also be replaced by any static element that exists at the time the handler is bound.

Comment: @nbrooks ok, i overlooked that table is dynamically generated.

Answer (score 4):

The jQuery [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method has been deprecated, and delegated event handlers should now use [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) (for older versions) or [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

The syntax for using `.on()` for delegated events is:

```
$(document).on('click','input.btnX', function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

Note that `document` here can also be replaced by any static parent element (of the future buttons) that exists at the time the handler is bound.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if it's better, but I use `parents()`...

```
$('input.btnX').click(function() {
    $(this).parents('tr').remove();
});
```

Comment: This will delete all parents which are `<tr>` elements, anywhere up the DOM tree -- so in a nested table you would remove the entire sub-table. `.closest()` gets the nearest parent and targets only that (it also doesn't have to traverse the full DOM tree)

Answer (score 2):

First of all change the `id="btnX"` to `class="btnX"`, since id should be unique.

then you can do this:

```
$( "input.btnX" ).live(function(event) {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

Comment: You wrote that the table is built dynamically, does that mean by Javascript?

Comment: Edited my answer, yes you should use live since it is dynamic

Answer (score 2):

First thanks everyone, I want to share and give back from the error I was able to solve from this thread, my own version of solution:

**Solution Step 1: In my setup using "closest" instead of parent/parents(also deletes parent so not for me) worked for me:**

```
$("#container1").on('click','#remove',function(e) {
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
});
```

**Solution step 2: Since it is 'tr', placed your the javascript reference id [i.e. #container1], on the 'table' instead on 'tr' otherwise there will be a design error**

```
    <table id="container1">
```

**Solution step 3: Don't forget to activiate jquery in your page:**

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input.btnX").live("click", function(event) {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});​
```

This fixes your problem, see [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h9DKW//3/) which shows it working.

Here is an [update](http://jsfiddle.net/h9DKW/2/) that shows it working with dynamic tables