# How to select a certain cell from a table

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 14 generated cells.

How can I select a specific cell from the 14 cells and control it? I want only one cell to be unique, the rest to be how they are displayed in the code, normally.

```js
var isCol = 0;
var board = [];
for (r = 0; r < 7; r++) {
  var line = [];
  for (c = 0; c < 7; c++) {
    line.push(r);
  }
  board.push(line);
}


function prs(c, r) {
  showTable(c, r);
  isCol = (isCol + 1) % 2;
}

function toColor(col, row, chosen_col, chosen_row) {
  var ret = false;
  switch (isCol) {
    case 0:
      if (row == chosen_row) {
        ret = true;
      }
      break;
    case 1:
      if (col == chosen_col) {
        ret = true;
      }
      break;
  }

  return ret;
}

function showTable(chosen_col, chosen_row) {
  var str = "";
  str += "<table border=1>";
  for (row = 0; row < 7; row++) {
    str += "<tr>";
    for (col = 0; col < 7; col++) {
      str += "<td onclick='prs(" + col + "," + row + ")'";
      if (toColor(col, row, chosen_col, chosen_row)) {
        str += " class='grn' ";
      }
      str += ">";
      str += RandomGenerator(50, 500);
      str += "</td>";
    }
    str += "</tr>";
  }
  str += "</table>";

  document.getElementById("ff").innerHTML = str;
}



function RandomGenerator(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}



showTable(-1);
```

```css
td {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}

td:hover {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.grn {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id='ff'></div>
```

Comment: add an `id` for each cell, then use `document.getElementById("idYouWant")` and you'll have the cell

Comment: If it's a predetermined cell, meaning you know which one it is before the user visits the page, then it would be best to use an ID or a class. If the selected cell is dependent on other factors on the other hand, you might want to look into JavaScript's [`querySelector()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp) method, as well as this [list of CSS selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) which you can use with it.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Don't worry about writing the perfect question, we just ask that you do your best, and we'll try to massage it into something that accomplishes your purpose. As "[ask]" suggests, if you're having a hard time ask a peer to proof-read and help clarify.

Comment: The use of specific IDs, one for each cell, makes sense. You can easily select a cell that way, or randomly do it if that's your goal.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a ID for that row

EG

```
<td id = "uniqueCell"> ... </td>
```

Then in your javascript you can do the following.

```
var uniqueCell = document.getElementById('uniqueCell');
```

then use that variable to do what you need to do

Comment: Oh I see, that occurred to me but i thought it wouldn't work for some stupid reasons,   currently I'm trying to get the output to give me ID for each Cell currently, i'm not getting any errors but when i click on the website, i get white screen, any tips would be appreciated

Comment: Sorry for the delay! Are you referring to the id number in your table that corresponds to that cell?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/r4tqoz something like this, for each cell to have his own ID.

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5589420/select-tr-by-id-with-jquery